# SSIS Bids 2008 package deployment

Tags: ssis

I am developing a SSIS package using BIDS 2008 which is for SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to deploy my application in DEV and QA. Would generating a dtsConfig for both environments sufficient for deployment. I am planning a file based deployment where I deploy the package and dtsConfig file on a server location. I have included the configuration file in the job step of the job. So what I understand is if there are two enviornments ,I would need to create two job scripts. Am I right ?

Comment: That's correct provided they both are needed to run at same time in different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two different job scripts if there are any differences in the name/location of either the package or the config file between the two environments.

If you are doing a file system deployment, and using relative/local path to specify the location of the package and config (in other words, you don't have to specify the servername in the path) then the same job script should work in both environments.